# JavaScript: Print argument received by function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-5

In Javascript ES5, is there any in-built object or array where arguments received by a function ? My need is, I have a function which improved recently but I want to add backlog support as well for other classes which are using this old API.

So if no arguments passed, I execute one block of code and with arguments, other block.

Any suggestions/help much appreciated.

Comment: You can use `arguments` and it is an array of all the arguments passed to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may use the `arguments` keyword, for example,

```
function f() {
  return arguments.length
}
```

```
console.log(f(1)) // 1
console.log(f(1,2)) // 2
```

The `arguments` keyword-variable can be treated as normal JavaScript arrays.

For more information, please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments